# HDMI Video on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hdmi, nvidia-optimus, dell-vostro

I have a Dell 3750 Vostro laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with an NVIDIA GT 525M graphics card.  I recently purchased an external monitor, which has both HDMI and VGA input.  The VGA input works perfectly, however the HDMI says "No Signal Detected".  I would love to use the HDMI connection to this monitor - but I have had no success whatsoever getting it to work.

I have installed Bumblebee, and I have also run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.  Neither of these had any effect on the HDMI output.  Is there anything else I can try?  Here is the output from `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 214mm
   1600x900       60.3*+
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I notice that there is no HDMI entry - is this perhaps part of the problem?  Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you own a digital TV try this: disconnect the digital signal to it at the TV end. Connect your monitor instead. If this works, your monitor is fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the monitor itself is fine.  I think the problem is that Ubuntu is not outputting the HDMI signal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes maybe your HDMI port is missing/broken or not detected correctly by Ubuntu. See the result of mine:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Solutions:

1. remove `Bumblebee` packages then check again.
2. remove `Bumblebee` and install Nvidia driver from typing "Additional Drivers" in dash and installing another one that listed under there.
3. re-install Ubuntu and check without installing `Bumblebee` and `Nvidia driver`
4. or just try to use HDMI out of a Live-System

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem, but when I run Ubuntu from a Live-USB the HDMI out is detected, even if nothing is displayed.  I'm not sure if that means the problem is with the NVIDIA drivers or Bumblebee on my original system.  Neither removing Bumblebee nor reinstalling NVIDIA's drivers made any difference.

Comment: Then you have an extra solution I said in step2 install another version of Nvidia driver under list. I can not say actually your problem is about Nvidia driver but may be in 99% relate to Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

try to go in the **BIOS** and set the video out put to nvidia only.

here my xrandr without HDMI connected (removed few lines for readability)

```
tilo@T-G73:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
...
   800x600        60.0  
   800x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

here after I connect HDMI (removed few lines for readability)
It is aATI card tho

```
tilo@T-G73:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
...
   800x600        60.0  
   800x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
DFP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     60.1     30.0     24.0     60.0     30.0     24.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1776x1000      59.9     24.0     60.0     30.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     30.0     24.0  
   1400x1050      60.0     30.0     24.0  
...
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     30.0     24.0     60.0  
   1152x648       59.9  
   1024x600       75.0     70.1     30.0     24.0     60.0  
   800x600        30.0     24.0     72.2     75.0     60.3  
   800x480        30.0     24.0     72.2     75.0     60.3  
   720x480        30.0     24.0     60.0     59.9  
   640x480        30.0     24.0     75.0     72.8     66.6     59.9  
CRT2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```